# Why is 'gulp watch' not updating?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

There are probably a couple of little style issues here, but mostly this works. However, it doesn't seem to be watching changes to `styles/*.scss` files or new SCSS in that folder. Same thing with Javascript: `scripts/*.js` isn't updating on watch.

Could also stand to combine the SCSS and CSS without destroying the sourcemap, but that's not really important. Right now, just getting live updates to work would be nice.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
const babel = require('gulp-babel')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const browserSync = require('browser-sync')
const clean = require('gulp-clean')
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

const gulpfn = require('gulp-fn')
const fs = require('fs');

const util = require('gulp-util');
let config = { production: !!util.env.production }

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('build', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean())
        .pipe(gulpfn(function (file) { 
            if (!fs.existsSync('build')){
                fs.mkdirSync('build');
            } 
        }));    
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: "./build"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp.src(['source/styles/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(config.production ? minifyCSS() : util.noop())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src('source/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015', 'es2016']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(config.production ? uglify() : util.noop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('external-scss', function(){
  gulp.src(['external/font-awesome-4.7.0/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(config.production ? minifyCSS() : util.noop())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

const STATIC_STYLES = ['source/styles/**/*.css']
const STATIC_HYPERTEXT = ['source/**/*!template.html', 'source/**/*.html']
const STATIC_TEMPLATES = ['source/templates/*.template.html']

gulp.task('static-sources', function(){
  gulp.src(STATIC_STYLES)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'))
  return gulp.src(STATIC_HYPERTEXT)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'styles', 'scripts', 'external-scss', 'static-sources'], function(){
  gulp.src(['external/font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts'));
  gulp.src( 'external/font-awesome-4.7.0/scss/*.scss', ['external-scss']);

  gulp.src(['external/fccfavicons-master/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/fccfavicons-master'));

  gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery/dist/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/jquery/dist'));

  gulp.src(['node_modules/lodash/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/lodash'));

  gulp.src(['node_modules/normalize.css/*.css']).pipe(gulp.dest('build/external/normalize.css'));

  gulp.watch('source/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('source/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  let static_sources = []
  static_sources.push(...STATIC_HYPERTEXT)
  static_sources.push(...STATIC_STYLES)
  gulp.watch(static_sources, ['static-sources']);

  gulp.watch('*.html', ['bs-reload']);
});
```

Comment: I see a return statement in your 'scripts' task but not in the others.

Comment: I dont think that matters? When I change a script in scripts, watch doesn't catch the change.

Comment: ooh thanks. that was .. so yeah that was it.

Comment: I added it as an answer since it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add return statements in your other tasks, besides scripts, to signal to gulp that they have all finished.